grpc-java, SNI isn't send along in TLS request
working on a grpc service atm. Server is written in c# and has to be reachable through localhost and the docker hostname. Solution to have to SSL certs => SNI.
clients are written in python and java. python client has no problem at all.
java client states "io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Connection closed while performing TLS negotiation" (full error at the end). Used text as a template.
Java ManagedChannel creator:
TlsChannelCredentials.Builder tlsBuilder = TlsChannelCredentials.newBuilder();
                ChannelCredentials tlsChannelCredentials = tlsBuilder.trustManager(new File("certificate.pem")).build();
                channel = Grpc.newChannelBuilder("localhost:50051", tlsChannelCredentials)
                        .overrideAuthority("localhost")
                        .build();

Error Message:
[21:08:05] [Server thread/ERROR] [ne.mi.ev.EventBus/EVENTBUS]: Exception caught during firing event: UNAVAILABLE: Connection closed while performing TLS negotiation
Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
    Index: 1
    Listeners:
        0: NORMAL
        1: ASM: io.github.bleyava.sspwhitelist.SSPWhitelist@f20101c onPlayerJoin(Lnet/minecraftforge/event/entity/player/PlayerEvent$PlayerLoggedInEvent;)V
        2: net.minecraftforge.eventbus.EventBus$$Lambda$4176/0x000001ba479c3948@6a06b08f
        3: ASM: net.minecraftforge.common.ForgeInternalHandler@7b5d739c playerLogin(Lnet/minecraftforge/event/entity/player/PlayerEvent$PlayerLoggedInEvent;)V
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Connection closed while performing TLS negotiation
Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
    at TRANSFORMER/sspwhitelist@1.0.0/io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:268)
    at TRANSFORMER/sspwhitelist@1.0.0/io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:249)
    at TRANSFORMER/sspwhitelist@1.0.0/io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:167)
    at TRANSFORMER/sspwhitelist@1.0.0/sspWhitelist.TokenManagerGrpc$TokenManagerBlockingStub.checkWhitelist(TokenManagerGrpc.java:213)
    at TRANSFORMER/sspwhitelist@1.0.0/io.github.bleyava.sspwhitelist.grpc.MessageSender.checkWhitelist(MessageSender.java:78)
    at TRANSFORMER/sspwhitelist@1.0.0/io.github.bleyava.sspwhitelist.SSPWhitelist.onPlayerJoin(SSPWhitelist.java:31)
    at net.minecraftforge.eventbus.ASMEventHandler_0_SSPWhitelist_onPlayerJoin_PlayerLoggedInEvent.invoke(.dynamic)
    at MC-BOOTSTRAP/eventbus@5.0.3/net.minecraftforge.eventbus.ASMEventHandler.invoke(ASMEventHandler.java:85)
    at MC-BOOTSTRAP/eventbus@5.0.3/net.minecraftforge.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:302)
    at MC-BOOTSTRAP/eventbus@5.0.3/net.minecraftforge.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:283)
    at TRANSFORMER/forge@40.2.0/net.minecraftforge.event.ForgeEventFactory.firePlayerLoggedIn(ForgeEventFactory.java:833)
    at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.server.players.PlayerList.m_11261_(PlayerList.java:238)
    at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.server.network.ServerLoginPacketListenerImpl.m_143699_(ServerLoginPacketListenerImpl.java:138)
    at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.server.network.ServerLoginPacketListenerImpl.m_10055_(ServerLoginPacketListenerImpl.java:125)
    at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.server.network.ServerLoginPacketListenerImpl.m_10050_(ServerLoginPacketListenerImpl.java:69)
    at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.network.Connection.m_129483_(Connection.java:241)
    at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.server.network.ServerConnectionListener.m_9721_(ServerConnectionListener.java:143)
    at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.m_5703_(MinecraftServer.java:916)
    at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.m_5703_(DedicatedServer.java:326)
    at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.m_5705_(MinecraftServer.java:842)
    at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.m_130011_(MinecraftServer.java:685)
    at TRANSFORMER/minecraft@1.18.2/net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.m_177918_(MinecraftServer.java:261)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at TRANSFORMER/sspwhitelist@1.0.0/io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelInactive(SslHandler.java:1155)
    at TRANSFORMER/sspwhitelist@1.0.0/io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:305)
    at TRANSFORMER/sspwhitelist@1.0.0/io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
    at TRANSFORMER/sspwhitelist@1.0.0/io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:274)
    at TRANSFORMER/sspwhitelist@1.0.0/io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1405)
    at TRANSFORMER/sspwhitelist@1.0.0/io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:301)
    at TRANSFORMER/sspwhitelist@1.0.0/io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
    at TRANSFORMER/sspwhitelist@1.0.0/io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:901)
    at TRANSFORMER/sspwhitelist@1.0.0/io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$7.run(AbstractChannel.java:813)
    at TRANSFORMER/sspwhitelist@1.0.0/io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:173)
    at TRANSFORMER/sspwhitelist@1.0.0/io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:166)
    at TRANSFORMER/sspwhitelist@1.0.0/io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at TRANSFORMER/sspwhitelist@1.0.0/io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:566)
    at TRANSFORMER/sspwhitelist@1.0.0/io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at TRANSFORMER/sspwhitelist@1.0.0/io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at TRANSFORMER/sspwhitelist@1.0.0/io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 more
    Suppressed: io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.StacklessSSLHandshakeException: Connection closed while SSL/TLS handshake was in progress
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelInactive(Unknown Source)


c# appsettings.json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Trace",
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "Grpc": "Debug"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://*:50051",
        "Protocols": "Http2",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "certificates/certificate.pfx",
          "Password": ""
        },
        "Sni": {
          "sspwhitelist": {
            "Protocols": "Http2",
            "Certificate": {
              "Path": "certificates/server.pfx",
              "Password": ""
            }
          },
          "localhost": {
            "Protocols": "Http2",
            "Certificate": {
              "Path": "certificates/certificate.pfx",
              "Password": ""
            }
          },
          "127.0.0.1": {
            "Protocols": "Http2",
            "Certificate": {
              "Path": "certificates/certificate.pfx",
              "Password": ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

TLS in wireshark
enter image description here
I tried connecting to a grpc server using sni and tls.
was not able to connect no matter if using ManagedChannelBuilder or NettyChannelBuilder.

According to this answer SNI is never used for localhost (defined this way in TLS spec). May be it works assigning 127.0.0.1 via hosts file an additional host name and use this instead of localhost?
